# How to edit the left hand column and replace with values in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following text file:

[.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dzxr.png)

In the left hand column all the values are '0' is there a way to change only the left hand column to replace all the zeros with the value 15. I cant find all and replace as other columns contain '0' which cant be altered, this also cant be done manually as the file contains 10,000 lines. I'm wondering if this is possible from the command line or with a script.

Thanks

Comment: Using vi: `:%s/^[0]/15/`
Using sed:  `sed 's/^\s*./15/g' myfile.txt`

Comment: @bobdylan That worked well, thanks very much.

Comment: Please copy actual file content. It's a lot easier.

Comment: @SendIT, if you want to preserve the *whitespace* (space or tab) after the leading `0`, you can use a capture group and then reinsert it with a backreference, e.g. `sed 's/^0\(\s\)/15\1/'`. That way if it was a tab, you preserve the tab, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '$1 == 0 { $1 = 15 } 1' file.txt
```

Replaces the first column with 15 on each line only if the original value is 0.